# Query health check endpoints in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker, health-check

I implemented a health check endpoint following [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-6.0). My ASP.NET application is dockerized and runs using `docker-compose`, with the port mapped/exposed.

**Question:** I am not sure how to query the health check endpoint from clients such as postman.

When I send a `GET` request to the `/healthz` endpoint as the following, postman throws the following error.

```
http://host.docker.internal:1200/healthz
```

> Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established

while I can see the following in the logs of the docker container.

```
[05:01:03 DBG] Connection id "0HMLSHSV1HRD2" accepted.
[05:01:03 DBG] Connection id "0HMLSHSV1HRD2" started.
[05:01:03 INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://host.docker.internal:1200/healthz - -
[05:01:03 DBG] Wildcard detected, all requests with hosts will be allowed.
[05:01:03 VRB] All hosts are allowed.
[05:01:03 DBG] 1 candidate(s) found for the request path '/healthz'
[05:01:03 DBG] Request matched endpoint 'Health checks'
[05:01:03 DBG] Static files was skipped as the request already matched an endpoint.
[05:01:03 DBG] Https port '1200' loaded from configuration.
[05:01:03 DBG] Redirecting to 'https://host.docker.internal:1200/healthz'.
[05:01:03 DBG] Connection id "0HMLSHSV1HRD2" completed keep alive response.
[05:01:03 INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://host.docker.internal:1200/healthz - - - 307 0 - 89.5220ms
```

Comment: The log indicates that you have redirection to HTTPS enabled. Because you're making a request to HTTP, the server is trying to redirect you to HTTPS (status 307 = temporary redirect). It seems to think that both HTTP and HTTPS are on port 1200, which seems unlikely, and is probably the source of the issue you're facing.

Comment: Have you tried the same request using `https`?

Comment: Thanks @ProgrammingLlama the HTTP->HTTPS redirect was the answer.